# How to use middleware in all http request in nodejs express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am creating a middleware in the nodejs application and I want to add header in the request in middleware and send it to the my endpoint index.js request.

middleware1.js

```
exports.mw1 = function(req, res, next) {
  next();
};
```

middleware2.js

```
exports.mw2 = function(req, res, next) {
  next();
};
```

app.js

```
var mw1 = require("./middlewares/middleware1");
var mw2 = require("./middlewares/middleware2");

var combinedMiddleware = function compose(middleware) {
  return function(req, res, next) {
    connect
      .apply(null, middleware.concat(next.bind(null, null)))
      .call(null, req, res);
  };
};

app.use(combinedMiddleware([auth, audit]));
app.use("/", index);
```

index.js

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

router.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Welcome!!");
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I am trying to call it http://localhost:3000/ then it returns the 404 Not Found. Instead, it should redirect request to both middleware then to the index.js

```
GET / 404 8.700 ms - 139
```

Does anyone know whats wrong with it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I am missing something, but why you don't do:

```
var mw1 = require("./middlewares/middleware1");
var mw2 = require("./middlewares/middleware2");

app.use(mw1, mw2);
app.use("/", index);
```

And change your middleware to :

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    next();
};
```

Comment: I am getting `throw new TypeError('Router.use() requires middleware function but got a ' + gettype(fn));`

Comment: You need to export just the function in the middleware files:  `exports = function(...`

Comment: how  `module.exports` is different than `exports.mw2` or `exports.mw1` ?

Comment: If you write `module.exports` then require of this module will return you a function, if you write `exports.mw1` then require will return you `{mw1: this_function}`, so you would have to use your middleware `app.use(mw1.mw1)`

Comment: so module.exports returns a function and exports.something returns an object right ?

Comment: With `exports.something` you set a key for returning object, with `module.exports` you set the whole value. It does't have to be a function, `module.exports = {m1: function(){}}` will return you the same as `exports.m1 = function(){}`